# Kernel errors and more when trying to boot from "Bootable USB"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, kernel

I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my Dell XPS 15 9560. But on boot I'm getting kernel errors and more when trying too boot from the installation USB. I will link a picture for better understanding.

[image]

I've tried to boot Ubuntu, Elementary os and Redhat. Tried to use different "Bootable USB" creator tools. Also removed an old grub boot installation from the EFI partition.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release is it and what are your hardware specs, most importantly what CPU model do you have? Is it an Intel Skylake (6th generation) or newer?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop. And I have a Dell XPS 15 9560 with Nvidia gpu and Intel i7-7700HQ CPU

Comment: Yours is a Kabylake (7th generation), but the issue is the same that the 16.04 kernel (at least 16.04.0 uses 4.4 as GA kernel) doesn't support the integrated graphics of these new CPUs yet. You could try either installing 16.04.3 which should come with the 4.10 HWE kernel already, or 17.04 which also uses 4.10. Otherwise boot your 16.04 with `nomodeset` and update the kernel there.

Comment: This is an Nvidia issue.